# @microsoft/mgt Graph toolkit Compilation error after migrating from Angular 11 to Angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I was using the Microsoft toolkit in my angular 11 app. Everything was working fine. Then I was requested to upgrade to Angular 13. Even with the latest version of the toolkit(2.3.2 as of this post), I get compilation errors. The errors are on the library itself, not in the app. All the errors seem to be pointing to one of its dependencies, microsoft/fast-foundation

I am only using:

```
<mgt-person person-query="me" view="oneline"></mgt-person>
```

And I set it up in the app component:

```
Providers.globalProvider = new Msal2Provider({
                clientId: authConfig.azureClintId,
                authority: authConfig.azureTenantId
            });
```

But the compiler throws many errors like these:

```
Error: node_modules/@microsoft/fast-foundation/dist/fast-foundation.d.ts:6358:26 - error TS2320: Interface 'TextField' cannot simultaneously extend types 'FormAssociatedTextField' and 'DelegatesARIATextbox'.
  Named property 'ariaBusy' of types 'FormAssociatedTextField' and 'DelegatesARIATextbox' are not identical.

6358 export declare interface TextField extends StartEnd, DelegatesARIATextbox {
                              ~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@microsoft/fast-foundation/dist/fast-foundation.d.ts:6358:26 - error TS2320: Interface 'TextField' cannot simultaneously extend types 'FormAssociatedTextField' and 'DelegatesARIATextbox'.
  Named property 'ariaDisabled' of types 'FormAssociatedTextField' and 'DelegatesARIATextbox' are not identical.

6358 export declare interface TextField extends StartEnd, DelegatesARIATextbox {
                              ~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@microsoft/fast-foundation/dist/fast-foundation.d.ts:6358:26 - error TS2320: Interface 'TextField' cannot simultaneously extend types 'FormAssociatedTextField' and 'DelegatesARIATextbox'.
  Named property 'ariaHidden' of types 'FormAssociatedTextField' and 'DelegatesARIATextbox' are not identical.

6358 export declare interface TextField extends StartEnd, DelegatesARIATextbox {
                              ~~~~~~~~~
```

Does anyone have a solution to this? Are aware of this?

Thanks

Comment: delete your node_modules repo and npm install

Comment: Thanks, but I have done that multiple times to no effect

Answer (score 1):

Set the following in your tsconfig.json file.

```
{
  "skipLibCheck": true
}
```